Signing ECDSA P256 Sha256 using the ecdsa crate computes faulty signature
So I'm attempting to reproduce the steps in RFC 7515 Section A.3.1 in rust.
I have been struggling to produce the correct R and S values even with a very minimal example that just takes the raw strings of the RFC as input.
use ecdsa::SigningKey;
use elliptic_curve::SecretKey;
use eyre::Result;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    minimal_jws_signature()
}
fn minimal_jws_signature() -> Result<()> {
    let jws_signing_input = b"eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ";
    let key: SigningKey<p256::NistP256> = SigningKey::from(SecretKey::from_jwk_str("{\"kty\":\"EC\",\"crv\":\"P-256\",\"x\":\"f83OJ3D2xF1Bg8vub9tLe1gHMzV76e8Tus9uPHvRVEU\",\"y\":\"x_FEzRu9m36HLN_tue659LNpXW6pCyStikYjKIWI5a0\",\"d\":\"jpsQnnGQmL-YBIffH1136cspYG6-0iY7X1fCE9-E9LI\"}").unwrap());
    let (signature, _) = key.sign_recoverable(jws_signing_input).unwrap();
    println!("computed R: ");
    println!("{:#?}", signature.r().to_bytes());
    println!("computed S: ");
    println!("{:#?}", signature.s().to_bytes());
    Ok(())
}

This produces the output

computedR:[123,134,107,133,151,91,21,14,250,223,68,234,231,81,58,69,8,137,105,167,189,108,83,70,38,204,200,134,219,172,19,12,]
computedS:[239,59,109,107,204,126,250,89,234,250,201,25,246,101,189,248,86,50,38,221,197,81,151,72,144,114,214,223,226,224,88,223,]

which is different from the calculated R and S in the RFC
To my understanding sign_recoverable() when called on a SigningKey<p256::NistP256> should be using Sha256 to hash before from what I could tell looking at the documentation of the ecdsa crate. So exactly what RFC7515 specifies.
What am I missing here?
I have also attempted to use sign_prehash_recoverable() and computing the SHA256 hash beforehand, resulting in yet another byte sequence, tho frankly I have been unable to determine in what form ecdsa excpects the Sha hash to be.

Standard ECDSA is randomized (like FFDSA) and signing the same data with the same keypair multiple times produces a different signature each time. There is a deterministic variant but (1) JOSE/JWS doesn't use it and (2) I have no clue if rust implements it.

@dave_thompson_085 - The posted signature is already the deterministic signature. OP: For the non-deterministic variant, apply RandomizedSigner in conjunction with a CSPRNG.
